# Javascript: How to access an object based on a String associated with that object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api, object

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to make an app that uses the Facebook API.  The problem I'm having is that I have a class dedicated to saving some of the information of different people (one of these pieces of information being the Facebook ID of the person in String form.)  My goal is to access a specific object from an ArrayList of these people objects only knowing the Facebook ID associated with that object.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Simple fact here on StackOverflow.  Questions that include the code you're trying are many times more likely to get good, relevant answers.  Usually a few lines of the relevant code is way, way more descriptive than many words.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your string?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that returns the person object if it is in the array, and false otherwise:

```
var userArray = [{/* user1 */}, {id:'123',/* Brian */},{/* user3 */}];

function getUserById(id){
  for(var i=0, l=userArray.length; i<l; i++){
    if(ArrayList[i]['id'] == id) return userArray[i];
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
var Brian = getUserById('123');
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are accessed by a numeric index into the array and arrays are optimized for sequences of data with indexes starting at zero.  It doesn't sound like that's what you really want.

If you want to be able to index via the Facebook ID, then you probably want to use an object (not an array) and set the Facebook ID as the key by which you can set and get items from the object.

```
var users = {};

function addUser(facebookID, properties) {
    // save properties object for a given facebookID user
    users[facebookID] = properties;
}

function getUser(facebookID) {
    // return properties object for a given facebookID user
    return users[facebookID];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no ArrayList class. If you're stuck with objects being in an array, the best thing you can do is iterate over the array, or use array.filter with a callback function:
http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/filter

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use arrays you will have to have something like this, altough I like the mapApproach:

ArrayApproach:

```
facebookIds = ["123", "2413", "1234"];
facebookObjects = [ObjFor123, ObjFor2413, ObjFor1234];
function getObjectById(id) {
    var index = facebookIds.indexOf(id);
    if(index != -1) {
        return facebookObjects[index];
    }
}
```

MapApproach:

```
var facebookMap = {
     "id1": Obj1,
     "id2": Obj2
};

function getObjById(x) {
    return facebookMap[x];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search an array for an item, and if it exists, return that item. Assuming your list is unsorted, the simplest way to achieve this is would be with a [linear search](http://algorithms.openmymind.net/search/linear.html):

```
function fetchItem(array, prop, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i][prop] === value)
      return array[i];
  }
  return undefined;
}

// search an array "userArray" for an item whose facebookId property is "12345"
fetchItem(userArray, facebookId, "12345"); // returns user object or undefined
```

This is potentially slow if you have a lot of user objects stored in the array. If your object appears last in the array, the function will have to check every single item in the array before returning your result.

It would be better to store the users in a data structure like `Object`. You can store key/value pairs where the key is equal to a unique identifier like `facebookId`, and the value is the rest of the user object:

```
var userCollection = {
  "12345": { name: 'foo' },
  "12346": { name: 'bar' },
  "12347": { name: 'baz' }
};
```

Assuming you already know the `facebookId` whose owner you are looking for, you can retrieve the user object directly, without having to search through anything:

```
userCollection["12346"]; // { name: 'bar' }
```

The `Object` class is much better suited for storing and accessing an unordered collection than `Array` is.